# Php - Pdo Ssh Tunnel

Tags: php, database, pdo, connection, ssh-tunnel

right now i am creating a ssh tunnel, so i can connect to my remote database, but for some reason the connection is still refusing...
my script:

```
try {

    $host = 'remote host';
    $sshuser = 'ssh user';
    $sshpass = 'ssh password';
    $dbuser = 'db user';
    $dbpass = 'db user';
    $dbname = 'db name';

    shell_exec("ssh -p$sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 $sshuser@$host");

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3307;dbname=' .$dbname. '', $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from table");

    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    print_r ($result);

    shell_exec("kill $(ssh-pid)");

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

And as a result i get:

```
Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'host' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Comment: Does the ssh tunnel stay active? Is a db server running locally on port 3307 already? What's the real MySQL servers connection/auth permission for that user?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

### This is what worked for me

**VM and VPN**

If you have a virtual machine then ssh to that virtual machine first.
If you get DNS issues, use the google dns: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
Change `127…` to `8.8.8.8`

my tunnel requires me to connect though a vpn, I used openvpn, you can install it like this:

```
sudo yum -y install openvpn
```

connect to the vpn
download myconfig.ovpn from the vpn provider

```
sudo openvpn --config myconfig.ovpn
```

**SSH Key**

upload your key to the virtual machine
fix the permissions

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/my-private-ssh-key
```

**Port forward**

```
ssh -f -N -i ~/.ssh/my-private-ssh-key yourname@yoursshserverdomain.com -L 3307:yourmysqldbdomain.com:3306
```

`-f` will run it in the background
`-L` will forward `127.0.0.1:3307` to point to `yourmysqldbdomain.com:3306`

note that using `localhost` didn't work in my case, had to use `127.0.0.1` for the current virtual machine local ip.

you can remove the `-f` and `-L` conditions and instead add `-v` to do some debugging, like so

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/my-private-ssh-key yourname@yoursshserverdomain.com
```

**Connect with mysql**

```
mysql -u yourdbusername -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -p
```

**Connect with PHP PDO**

```php
$db_server = '127.0.0.1';
$db_port = '3307';
$db_name = 'yourdbname';
$db_user = 'yourdbusername';
$db_pass = 'yourdbpassword';

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$db_server.';dbname='.$db_name.';port='.$db_port;
$driver_options = [
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5, // timeout in seconds
];               
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $driver_options);
```

**Remove the port forwarding**

Once you are finished you can kill the process by finding the id like this:

```
ps aux | grep ssh
sudo kill 123123 // replace 123123 with the id of the process
```

Answer (score 0):

`-p$sshpass ssh` This particular part of the ssh command seems a bit odd to me. There should probably be a space after `-p` and the `ssh` shouldn't be there too.

Also, `-p` option is for port, not password.